# Setting transparent property on an already created window in electron

Tags: electron

Do you guys know if I can set BrowserWindow property to be transparent in the middle of my program and not during the creation time ?, since css based animations on window work only if its transparent, I need the window to show up with background color and then go transparent just before my animation kicks in

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make a window frameless or transparent after its been created.